# What is the best way to disconnect user after exactly 5min of inactivity on Android?

Tags: android, session, alarmmanager, android-workmanager, disconnect

I am trying to implement a way of automatically disconnect user after **EXACTLY** 5 minutes of inactivity on my Android App.

I was using AlarmManager before, but since the last changes on Android 13 & 14, I had to change from exact alarms to inexact, which does not meet my needs.

I tried using WorkManager but the fact that "killing" the app from the multitasks screen does not terminate my workers is a problem.

Comment: Do they stay in one activity for the 5 minutes? You can just set a timer, even across multiple activities you could set a timer. Timing 5minutes inside your app is possible if you start the timer in onResume and stop/clear it in onPause. (excluding multi-screen scenario's for now)

Comment: What do you mean by "disconnect"? Does the app being terminated count?  If so, just use Handler.postDelayed and reset the timer every time the user interacts.